# Requiring package only for specific server with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a couple of servers that all use the same git repo. They auto deploy when I push updates to the master branch. Some of these are *app servers*, some are *cron servers*, etc.

I am using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for some of my background tasks. Is it possible to only require puppeteer on the *cron servers*? I know there are devDependencies but that would install PHPUnit, etc, and it just doesn't seem right. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: How do you distinguish in code between `cron server` and `app server`? Do you have some *flag* for it?

Comment: There is no distinction in the code at all.

Comment: So it means there is no way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some batch script that executes before composer:

```
if [[ "$SERVER_TYPE" == "dev-server" ]];
then
    cp composer.json.dev composer.json
else
    cp compsoer.json.prod composer.json
```

*code is may not work, as it's out-of-head written* but idea is clear I think:

If your environment variable `SERVER_TYPE` is dev, then copy dev-specific file, else - copy other one.